# Typical page size for jpeg converted to pdf in Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, file-conversion

I'm trying to use Adobe Acrobat to convert several images taken with my phone to a pdf document for ease of sharing.
[image]

I have selected the "Smaller File Size" option from Acrobat's Combine Files tool.
[image]

But after converting the pages come out to be outrageously large, way too large to display usefully on the web interface where I'm trying to share this information. I tried printing to a pdf to force a letter paper size, but then the file size spiked from 3 KB to 2 MB. This seems like such an obvious problem, I can't believe that Adobe wouldn't have a solution here. Can someone help me out?
[image]

Comment: "the web interface where I'm trying to share this information" I do not understand why you need to "convert" to PDF, a native format for the web is JPG, not PDF. a PDF is only a container with the image inside.

Comment: And I am assuming when you refer to "size" you really mean "weight" aka Kilobytes or Megabytes, not A4 or letter, right?

Comment: 2 MB is not especially excessive for a PDF containing several page-sized photographs/scans.  Not sure if there really is a problem here.  What size are the originals in KB/MB?